# Test Management Tool Integration with JIRA

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, qa-developer, agile, jira

My question here is I would like to integrate Zephyr or any other tool with **JIRA** which could answer all my queries below:

1. What is Zephyr/any tool all about and how its going to work for QA ?
2. What are the advantages when compared to other tools ?
3. Will it support if I want to integrate with other tool ( JIRA ) ?
4. What if we have 'n' number of existing projects so once I install Zephyr/any tool what should be the preliminary checks which has to be performed from our end?
5. What version of JIRA will Zephyr/any tool support if we integrate ?
6. How many users can use Zephyr/any tool ?
7. How it works for different size projects ?
8. How it works in case of Test Case Preparation, Execution, Reporting ?
9. How good is the tool when I integrate Zephyr/any tool with JIRA ?
10. Once I uninstall the tool Zephyr/any tool will it hamper any of my data which is present previously ?
11. How about the maintenance & support ?
12. What if I wanna crash any project completely ?
13. Other than Zephyr/any tool server where the complete data can be stored ? Can we make a copy of it ?
14. Does this particular tool support Automation as well ?

Can someone help me finding solution?

**Note :** Ready to go with Paid tools but it should answer my above mentioned queries.

Comment: Not to be rude or anything, but there are a LOT of questions here. People only have time to answer one or two questions. Have you attempted your own research of these tools? a lot of your questions can be solved this way. I would focus only 2 or so questions that you absolutely cannot find somewhere else.

Comment: @DEnumber50 I understand what you are saying, atleast I can get answers for few questions of mine that is also helpful. what if I post part by part then people will say its duplicacy ! I need an answer for this else its tough for me to go with what kind of tools.

Comment: Maybe the question you are looking for is "How do I do test tool evaluation?", because really you have to find out for yourself if the tool does what you need it todo. Make a list of requirements and give it a test run :)

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal Nope.. I m looking into the tool which is best suited for the above requirement ! I thought that Stack Exchange helps me in getting quick answers since I do not have time to run through all the free tools or get help from the support :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of answering to your individual questions, I will just answer the last sentence: Help you finding the solution.

For many Test management tools that integrate with Jira, the way of working will support you well ( you are satisfied with questions 3 to 14 ) What will be ( a bit ) different, is their approach to test management. ( Questions 1 and 2 )

So I suggest you to try out few tools that have the integration to Jira and see if you like them and if they are fit for your organization. Our company uses Meliora Testlab, you mentioned Zephyr and HP ALM supports integration as well. There are also many, many others. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/app/jira/popular?category=Testing+%26+QA

What you might want to consider if you want to have one way or two-way integration with Jira. One way is simpler - you edit the issues always in Jira. Downside is that they might not support your testing quite as well ( how to pick test cases which found the defects for retesting, for example)